# Can I express this more succinctly by using an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

```
switch(ID)
{
    case "CustomReportsContainer":
        foreach (var report in SessionRepository.Instance.CustomReports.ToList())
        {
            var reportItem = new RadListBoxItem(report.Name, report.ID.ToString());
            if (!Items.Any(item => int.Equals(item.Value, reportItem.Value)))
            {
                Items.Add(reportItem);
            }
        }
        break;
    case "HistoricalReportsContainer":
        foreach (var report in SessionRepository.Instance.HistoricalReports.ToList())
        {
            var reportItem = new RadListBoxItem(report.Name, report.ID.ToString());
            if (!Items.Any(item => int.Equals(item.Value, reportItem.Value)))
            {
                Items.Add(reportItem);
            }
        }
        break;
}
```

HistoricalReports and CustomReports are collections of different types, but I am interested in the same two properties from each object type. I thought that I should be able to use LINQ's Select, and create a list of anonymously typed objects.

I can't create an implicitly typed variable without assigning to it, though. And since I'm inside of a Switch statement's scope... I can't assign to var inside of the switch statement, then move the rest of the code outside of the switch statement.

How should I express this code? Is the current implementantion 'best'?

Uggh, close. Can I do anything with this? It's through our API so I can't modify any deeper.

```
ReportServices.GetAllCustomReports().Select(report => new { report.Name, report.ID} ).ToList().ForEach(customReport => _customReports.Add(customReport));

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'CableSolve.Web.Dashboard.IReport'
```

Comment: That's not helpful at all! I am in the process of refactoring right now, which is why I'm here, asking questions and learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CustomReport` and `HistoricalReport` should implement an `IReport` interface that contains the `Id` and `Name` properties (at minimum).

```
switch(ID)
{
    case "CustomReportsContainer":
        AddReportItems(SessionRepository.Instance.CustomReports);
        break;
    case "HistoricalReportsContainer":
        AddReportItems(SessionRepository.Instance.HistoricalReports);
        break;
}

private void AddReportItems(IEnumerable<IReport> reports)
{
    foreach (var report in reports)
    {
        var reportItem = new RadListBoxItem(report.Name, report.ID.ToString());
        if (!Items.Any(item => int.Equals(item.Value, reportItem.Value)))
        {
            Items.Add(reportItem);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

In response to your additional questions, would it be possible for `GetAllCustomReports` to return a type that implements the `IReport` interface? This would eliminate the need for projecting to an anonymous type via `Select(report => new { report.Name, report.ID} )` and should resolve the remaining issue.

Comment: So I'm really close.. and can see a lot of places where my code improves by using this interface. Could you check the edit to my original post and see if the limitations introduced by our API invalidate my ability to use IReport?

Answer (score 2):

If the items share an interface or base type (or can you change them so they do) - then you would be able to express the LINQ query based on that type.

If not, you could type them as `dynamic` if you are on C# 4, since they share the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the same two properties and they have the same name, perhaps you have a good candidate for a small interface?